# regexp to match numbre of chars not equal to

Tags: regex, regex-negation

is there a way to write a regexp to match any number of characters but N?

Like /^\d{**not** 3}$/ -

11 - ok

111  - not ok

1111  - ok

Comment: Do you mean you want to only match a string  that only consists of digits and the number of digits can be 1 to 2 and 4 to "infinity"? `^(?!\d{3}$)\d+$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex using an alternation:

```
^(?:\d{1,2}|\d{4,})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpiHYi/6)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^` - Start
- `(?:` - start non-capturing group

  - `\d{1,2}` - match 1 or 2 digits
  - `|` - OR
  - `\d{4,})` - match 4+ digits
- `)` end non-capturing group
- `$` - Start